# Check to call stopForeground(true)

Tags: android, service, alarmmanager

In my app, I use `AlarmManager` to start `Foreground Service` to do a job at specific time in the future, then call `stopForeground(true)` when the job done.

I got a problem on below case.

**Job 1** : Time scheduled at **10:00 AM**, service starts and do a long task. It take about **5** minutes to complete.

**Job 2:** Time scheduled at **10:01 AM**, service starts and do a slightly task. It take only **1** minute to complete.

As you can see, when time is **10:02 AM**, **job2** completed and **job1** has not completed yet. So if I call **stopForeground(true)** from job2, it will dismiss the notification and also stop the foreground, job1 is impacted and running as background now.

So I consider whether I can know if an "instance" job is running foreground and I should not call `stopForeground(true)`.
Sorry for my bad English.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using just one Service with two jobs or  two separate services?

Check that the NOTIFICATION_IDs you're using to `startForeground()` are different each time, otherwise I guess JOB2 will always dismiss the notification for JOB1 as well